# is it possible to define a constructor for deftype?

Tags: clojure

a trivial case for a constructor for deftype

```
(deftype Atom [v]
    ...)
```

and I want v to be wrapped in an atom so that

```
@(.v (Atom. 1)) => 1
```

is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to provide your own implementation for you type rather than using the one that is auto generated for you?

Comment: I was looking to do mutable state... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. If you really want to go the OO way of constructor then you will need to use [gen-class](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class).

In functional world it is very simple using a function.

```
(defn createAtom [v] (Atom. (atom v)))
@(.v (createAtom 1)) => 1
```

Comment: How would you go about using protocols on gen-class?

Comment: If you want to define custom constructor you have to use gen-class or write your solution in Java. On how to use gen-class, please read this [tutorial](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html).

Answer (score 0):

Same question was asked before, please see this: [Add constructor to deftype created class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515162/add-constructor-to-deftype-created-class)